# 24c32a eeprom write operation not working with attiny402..am i mistaken?

Tags: c, embedded, eeprom, attiny, proteus

```
#define sda_on PORTA_DIRSET = PIN1_bm ; PORTA_OUTSET = PIN1_bm ;
#define sda_read PORTA_DIRCLR = PIN1_bm ;while(PORTA_IN & (PIN1_bm));PORTA_DIRSET = PIN1_bm ;
#define sda_off PORTA_DIRSET = PIN1_bm ;PORTA_OUTCLR = PIN1_bm ;
#define scl_on PORTA_DIRSET = PIN2_bm ;PORTA_OUTSET = PIN2_bm ;
#define scl_off PORTA_DIRSET = PIN2_bm ;PORTA_OUTCLR = PIN2_bm ;
#include <xc.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
void i2c_start(void)
{
    sda_on;
    scl_on;
    _delay_ms(10);
    sda_off;
    _delay_ms(10);
    scl_off;
}
void i2c_stop(void)
{
    sda_off;
    scl_off;
    _delay_ms(10);
    scl_on;
    _delay_ms(10);
    sda_on;
}
void i2c_data_write(unsigned char data)
{
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        if(data & 0x80) 
        {
            sda_on;
        }
        else sda_off;
        _delay_ms(10);
        scl_on;
        _delay_ms(10);
        scl_off;
        data = data << 1;
    }
    scl_on;
    sda_on;
    _delay_ms(10);
    sda_read;
    _delay_ms(10);   
    scl_off;
    _delay_ms(10);
}
```

Its a just write operation in 24c32a eeprom using by Attiny402..its not working ..im using simulating with debugging by proteus software....i2c debugger gives always question mark while im run the simulation help me..

Comment: Are you missing a delay between the last and first signal transitions of your `for()`loop?

Answer (score 1):

a quick answer: those macros should be changed to use bit-wise-OR assignment `|=` and bit-wise-AND assignment `&=` instead.

```
#define sda_on PORTA_DIRSET = PIN1_bm ; PORTA_OUTSET = PIN1_bm ;
#define scl_on PORTA_DIRSET = PIN2_bm ;PORTA_OUTSET = PIN2_bm ;
```

The macro `sda_on` sets `PORTA_OUTSET` to the value `PIN1_bm`, while the macro `scl_on` sets `PORTA_OUTSET` to the value `PIN2_bm`.

From those macros, we know the two pins `sda` and `scl` are both on `PORTA`, and the macros operate with bit-mask for the two pins. In general, a bit-mask of port pin would have only one bit set, like 0x01 or 0x02 or 0x04, and so on.

Then, at the beginning of `i2c_start()`, a `sda_on` is followed by a `scl_on`, that makes the value of `PORTA` set to `PIN2_bm` but not the correct value `PIN1_bm | PIN2_bm` which will set both pins to high level for the setup-time of a start-condition of i2c.

```
void i2c_start(void)
{
  sda_on; // PORTA_DIRSET = PIN1_bm ; PORTA_OUTSET = PIN1_bm ;
  scl_on; // PORTA_DIRSET = PIN2_bm ;PORTA_OUTSET = PIN2_bm ;
  // at this point, PORTA_DIRSET = PIN2_bm ;PORTA_OUTSET = PIN2_bm ;
  // But not, PORTA_DIRSET = PIN1_bm | PIN2_bm ;PORTA_OUTSET = PIN1_bm | PIN2_bm ;
  _delay_ms(10);
  sda_off;
  _delay_ms(10);
  scl_off;
}
```

So, the rough solution is to change the macros like the followings.

```
#define scl_on PORTA_DIRSET |= PIN2_bm ;PORTA_OUTSET |= PIN2_bm ;
#define scl_off PORTA_DIRSET &= ~PIN2_bm ;PORTA_OUTCLR &= ~PIN2_bm ;
```

Or, you could use two ports for the two pins, like `sda` on `PORTA` and `scl` on `PORTB`, if there is no other pin sharing the same port, then the bit-wise-OR assignment `|=` and bit-wise-AND assignment `&=` would be not necessary.